# Execute multiple async actions in the gulp task?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, gulp

I have a gulp task called `deploy` that copies files to my projects `wwwroot` folder using the `exec` command:

```
function deploy() {
    exec('robocopy CSS wwwroot\CSS *.css', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    });

    exec('robocopy CSS CSS *.css', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    }).;

    exec('robocopy JS wwwroot\\JS *.map', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    });
// ...
}
```

This used to work but as of Gulp 4.0, this gives the following error message: `Did you forget to signal async completion?`

According to the guide: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#signal-task-completion, all the recommended solutions seem to expect only one async function per task.

Is there a way to run these asynchronous functions in the same task?

Comment: What happens if you await the third `exec()` same as the other two?

Comment: Are you sure that `exec()` returns Promise, and if so why pass a callback?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Sorry, I copy/pasted in the middle of investigations.
The `exec()` did not return a promise, instead it returns a ChildProcess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping the `exec` calls in a `Promise` like so:

```
function multiExec(cmds) {
     var promises = [];
     for(var cmd of cmds) {
         promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             exec(cmd, (stdout, stderr, err) => {
                 if(err){
                     reject(err);
                 } else {
                     resolve();
                 });
             });
         });
     }
     return new Promise.all(promises);
}
```

And then used as so:

```
function deploy() {
    return multiExec(['robocopy CSS wwwroot\CSS *.css',
                      'robocopy CSS CSS *.css',
                      'robocopy JS wwwroot\\JS *.map']);
}
```